# mi <meta name="description" content="texto"> no se actualiza

Tags: html, html5, cache

Hola me gustaria saber si estoy cometiendo algún error o porque es que no se actualiza la info de esta etiqueta al buscar mi pagina

codigo del head:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Explora los productos en publicidad impresa y dijital para tú paletería!">
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <?php require_once("depen/links.php")?>
  </head>
```

imagen de como se muestra al buscar:
[image: imagen de muestra]

en un principio pensé que es por la chahe pero ya la he eliminado y a un sigu.

Answer (score 0):

Si realizaste el cambio de la descripción, en el caso de Google es posible que no se haya actualizado o indexado el contenido, debes ser consciente que puede tardar un tiempo en procesar los cambios realizados.

Puedes incrementar la [frecuencia de rastreo](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=es-419)